# Problems with log with logback-ecs-encoder

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, logging

I have an Spring-Boot project that works without problems and I want to add the ecs-encoder from Elastic so I can generate json logs that are ready for ElasctiSearch, my configuration is the following:

dependency added in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>co.elastic.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-ecs-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

logback-spring-xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring.log}"/>
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
        <include resource="co/elastic/logging/logback/boot/ecs-file-appender.xml" />
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
            <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        </root>
        <logger name="project.zuul.service.log" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="ECS_JSON_FILE"/>
        </logger>
    </configuration>
```

The class where i'm logging:

```
    @Log4j2
    public class ProjectLogger {

        private ProjectLogger() {
        }

        public static void logProjectInfo(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            log.trace(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object));
        }

    }
```

It is supossed to generate a log.json file with the json logs, but I'm still getting just the normal log and not the json log from ecs.

Comment: Have you also properly configured your `application.properties` file as [described here](https://github.com/elastic/ecs-logging-java/blob/master/logback-ecs-encoder/README.md#spring-boot-applications)?

Answer (score -1):

Here's the doc for configuring ECS.

You have to check the name of your ecs appender that you're referencing in :
   `<logger name="project.zuul.service.log" level="trace" additivity="false"> <appender-ref ref="ECS_JSON_FILE"/> </logger>`

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs-logging/java/current/setup.html